# Trying to build an app with convert real time speech to text

Tags: python, reactjs, azure, speech-to-text, azure-ai

I have been triying to create a real time speech to text using react js as front end and python flask as backend. using socket to connect between these to send real time data i have tried many ways but the data is not correctly converted or no result is printing as output. The python flask recieved the audio data continously as bytes and use `pushAudioStream` in azure python speech sdk to create a stream of AudioInputStream class and given it to configure conversation_transcriber of azure speech python sdk / speechRecognizer. but the result is not as satisfying please help with a suitable solution

i need output as a text which i have given as input as speech using react js in front end and flask as backend

Comment: please share the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

The code below is for speech-to-text applications using React as the frontend, Flask as the backend and Socket. IO.

- This sample is for implementation for transcribing audio using Azure Speech to Text.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import SpeechConfig, ResultReason
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio import AudioConfig, AudioStreamFormat, PullAudioInputStreamCallback
import io
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# Set up your Speech Config
speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="AzureSpeechKey", region="AzureSpeechregion")

class StreamBuffer(PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        super().__init__()
        self.stream = stream
        self.format = AudioStreamFormat(stream.sample_rate, stream.bits_per_sample, stream.channel_count)

    def read(self, buffer_size: int):
        data = self.stream.read(buffer_size)
        return data, len(data)

@socketio.on('audio')
def handle_audio(audio_data):
    audio_stream = io.BytesIO(audio_data)
    stream_buffer = StreamBuffer(audio_stream)

    # Configure your speech_recognizer
    speech_recognizer = speech_config.create_speech_recognizer()
    audio_config = AudioConfig(stream=stream_buffer)
    speech_recognizer.set_audio_config(audio_config)

    # Process audio stream
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

    # Emit the result back to the frontend
    if result.reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        socketio.emit('transcription', result.text)
    elif result.reason == ResultReason.NoMatch:
        socketio.emit('transcription', "No speech could be recognized")
    elif result.reason == ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        socketio.emit('transcription', "Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

```
import  React,  {  useState  }  from  'react';
import  axios  from  'axios';
import  Dropzone  from  'react-dropzone';
import  './App.css';
 
const  App = ()  =>  {
const  [transcription,  setTranscription] = useState('');
const  [file,  setFile] = useState(null);
const  onDrop = (acceptedFiles)  =>  {
setFile(acceptedFiles[0]);
};
const  onTranscribe = async  ()  =>  {
const  formData = new  FormData();
formData.append('audio',  file);

try  {
const  response = await  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/transcribe',  formData,  {

headers:  {

'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data',

},
});
setTranscription(response.data.transcription);
}  
catch (error) {

console.error('Error transcribing audio:',  error.message);
}
};

return (
<div  className="App">
<h1>Azure Speech to Text</h1>
<Dropzone  onDrop={onDrop}>

{({  getRootProps,  getInputProps  })  => (

<div  {...getRootProps()}  className="dropzone">

<input  {...getInputProps()}  />

<p>Drag & drop an audio file here, or click to select one</p>

</div>

)}

</Dropzone>

{file && <p>Selected File: {file.name}</p>}

<button  onClick={onTranscribe}  disabled={!file}>

Transcribe

</button>

{transcription && (

<div  className="transcription">

<h2>Transcription:</h2>

<p>{transcription}</p>

</div>

)}

</div>

);

};

export  default  App;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]